# Why doesn't jQuery function properly on keydown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this external jQuery code:

```
jQuery(document).one('keydown', 'g',function (evt){
    if ($("#tb").html() == "0")
    {
        $("#tb").html("Testing the chicken.")
    } else {$("#tb").html("Chickens fart too.")}
return false;});
```

There are no errors in console.

I know it's rather silly, but never mind the text in .html(). Anyways, whenever I go to the webpage it just replaces the default 0 in the page with nothing. Then, when I press any key nothing happens. Ultimately, what I want this script to do in the end is display the letter or number that the user types in the `tb` div.

P.S. I'm new to stackoverflow so please tell me if my formatting is wrong or if I broke a rule.

Okay, so I edited the code and here is what I have:

```
$('#tb').on("keydown", function(event) {
    if ($("#tb").html() == "0")
    {
        $("#tb").html("Testing the chicken.")
    } else {$("#tb").html("Chickens fart too.")}
});
```

It still doesn't work.

Comment: `g` is not a valid selector, did you want to _detect_ the letter `g` is that it?

Comment: @elclanrs Yes. I wanted it to run when I press g and then ultimately run no matter what key I press and record that key in an array.

Comment: The key is passed into `evt.which`, you just need to find the keycode for `g`.

Comment: `.one` should be `on` ?

Comment: @Jonathan: There's also `one` which attaches the event _only once_, but I don't know if that's what OP meant...

Comment: @elcanrs Could you clarify what you mean by that? What's the benefit of using on versus one and what is the keycode or evt.which? I'm very new to jQuery so I don't understand this all very well.

Comment: I would just check the docs: http://api.jquery.com/on/, http://api.jquery.com/one/, http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/. Everything is explained in detail there.

Comment: @elclanrs I did look at them and I can't seem to figure this out. I posted the edited code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A div element does not have a `keydown event`. Only element that have focus property can have it.

So I think you are referring to a input inside the div..

**HTML**

```
<div id="tb">
    <span class="output"></span>
    <input type="text" />
</div>
```

**JS**

```
// Delegating the event on input to it's container
$('#tb').on("keydown", 'input', function (event) {
    // $(this).val() - Gets the value of the input on keydown
    if ($(this).val() === "") {
        // Set the html for span inside div
        $(".output").html("Testing the chicken.");
    } else {
        $(".output").html("Chickens fart too.");
    }
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GmWNk/)**

```
// Bind event to the document which fires when document is focussed and 
// a key is pressed
$(document).on('keydown', function(event) {
    // Key code for g
    if(event.keyCode === 71) {
        // Bind the event to the input when g is pressed
        $('#tb input').on('keyup', inputKeydown);
        // unbind the event on document as no longet necessary
        $(document).off('keydown');
    }
    return;
});

function inputKeydown() {
    // $(this).val() - Gets the value of the input on keydown
    if ($(this).val() === "") {
        // Set the html for span inside div
        $(".output").html("Testing the chicken.");
    } else {
        $(".output").html("Chickens fart too.");
    }
}
```

**[Another Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GmWNk/1/)**

Comment: But you still used #tb so I don't understand.

Comment: `$('#tb').on("keydown", 'input', function (event) {` can be simply written as `$('input').on("keydown", function (event) {`

Comment: The example I have shown is for event delegation for dynamically created elements in future

Comment: okay. Thank you, but when I do event.which it returns a very random number. $("#tb").html(event.which);

Comment: `event.which` returns the key code of the key that was pressed.. Enter is 13 for example